# remove gravity from the accelerometer recordings by applying a high-pass Butterworth filter Android

Tags: android

As part of an Android project, I have to remove the value of gravity on the accelerometer values on the 3 axes using high-pass butterworth, but after several searches I have not found how to do it. I found on the Android site how to do with low pass filter

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)

   /*alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)*/
  /* with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant*/
  /* and dT, the event delivery rate*/

  final float alpha = 0.8;

  gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
  gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
  gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

  linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
  linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
  linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
```

but this is not my goal in addition I have seen comments that say that the code does not take into consideration the orientation of the smartphone and in the Code we find, alpha = 0.8, why they set exactly 0.8, I guess the value has an impact on the result. But my goal is not low pass filter but high-pass butterworth, please if anyone has an idea how to implement high-pass butterworth on Android, help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a little late my answer but If it is your first time working with filters I recommend read about FIR filters and use the matlab tool called fdatool, you can import the code and It could give you ideas of how to do that.

Comment: This reads like a link-only answer. It would help to include small code or even formula's for reference such as a simple implementation of a suitable filter.